# Firefox specific css issue (all versions all platforms) : form submit button flies off to the right

Tags: css, debugging

I've no idea why it does this only in Firefox, but the submit button of my form goes to the right side of the page as if floated, but it's not...

Here is the test page :
http://club-avantages.alarmefast.com/micro-wonderbox/

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to the `input` submit button.

Tested in Firefox 4.

I'm investigating *why* this works at the moment.

---

You have two floated elements above, and you want that button to be below all the floated elements. The proper solution *is* therefore `clear: both` - that's what it's for.

However, I can't (quickly) work out *why* different browsers are behaving differently here. I'm guessing that it's because `input` elements are bizarre creatures.

If you *really* want to know why, just say so, and I will take the page apart and find the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I don't understand why the clear was required : if you look at my code, the container of the floated elements already had the clearfix hack applied to it through its class.. ??

Comment: The `clearfix` class on the `form` is not doing anything here (you don't need it) in any browser -  testing with Chrome verifies this. I removed the `clear: both` fix from the button, and removed the `clearfix` class from the `form`. Nothing changed. Whereas doing the same steps with Firefox, the button just goes back to right.

Comment: What felt odd I guess is that the clearfix serves the purpose of preventing "container shrinkage". For instance, without clearing a container with only floated elements, it has no height etc etc

What I didn't know was that if you add an extra element that is not floated, then the clearfix indeed becomes effectively useless, since you have to apply a clear to the first non-floated element instead of the container...

Funny how you never stop learning :-) Thanks for the heads up Thirtydot !

Answer (score 1):

It's because your other two elements in the container are floated to the left.  If you add `clear:left` on your button, it should avoid the issue.